# Why do I have two (2) launchers after customizing my Unity setup with ccsm?

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz

Just installed Ubuntu Oneric (11.10) and Compizconfig Settings Manager, made some tweaks, everything is looking great. However, now I have two launchers and these settings do not start automatically if I logout and log back in.

I would appreciate any help you can provide.

PS: all my drivers are up to date, my PC is an Acer with a AMD Athlon 64x2 Dual core Processor and a Nvidia Graphic card with 3D capability.

Comment: Hi, Alguien habla espanol? Also, can you tell us whether you installed a dock or anything similar? A screenshot would help greatly in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Unity is a plugin in Compiz, and when you enable certain settings it activates Unity 3D, the unity version used with Compiz. This version will overlap Unity 2D native in 11.10. I fixed this by disabling the unity plugin in Compiz and re-enabling it. It then asked me to resolve conflicts, which I did. This disabled the Unity 2D and displayed only the customized one.