# How add a second Unity Launcher?

Tags: 11.10, unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to have 2 unity launchers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45301/possible-to-have-2-unity-launchers)

How can I add a second Unity Launcher to my Ubuntu 11.10?
It could be possible, because [someone have accidentaly done it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102425/why-do-i-have-two-2-launchers-after-customizing-my-unity-setup-with-ccsm)...

This **is not a duplicate** of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45301/possible-to-have-2-unity-launchers) - it was about Ubuntu 11.04 and I'm asking about 11.10 (there were many changes between .04 and .10)

Comment: Please star the other Questions to receive updates for possible new answers.

Answer (score 1):

You Can't, if you want another launcher I would suggest installing docky or cairo dock

Comment: Why I can't? When Domingo was playing with ccsm, he accidentaly done it, so it could be possible...

Comment: ccsm is full of bugs and is not technically a part of Unity.  If you really really want it ask Domingo.  The safest option is to use Docky or Cairo dock. IMOA

Comment: @Marqin I once had 2 Unity launchers accidentally show up on a previous setup, and trust me that it is probably not what you are thinking of. What I got was the Unity 2D launcher and 3D launcher showing at the same time on top of each other; this also duplicated the dash, Alt+Tab, etc. There were focus issues and it became a major headache until I got it resolved. It's not the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45301/possible-to-have-2-unity-launchers) is same

> Unfortunately it's not possible to have more than one launcher in
>   Unity.

if you want to move unity launcher to bottom read this webupd8 [post](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/how-to-move-unity-launcher-to-bottom-of.html)